# Creating provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning

I want to create provision certificate for development and testing purpose.

I login Apple web site and going to https://developer.apple.com/ios

But I did one mistake during certificate creation i revoking distribution profile... Now I am worried if I revoke distribution profile then the distribution binary on app store is not working if during this time any body download my application from app store? How do I go back if I revoke the distribution certificate?

If in not able to go back on real certificate then what is will be the solution of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, if you revoke the distribution certificate or profile, it only means that you can't create a new binary for Ad-Hoc or App Store until you create a new one. No problems, don't panic.

Oh and you can't "go back", once it's gone - it's gone, just create a new one.